# How to Assign the Numbers Automatically in This Enumerate Environment

Tags: numbering, listings, enumerate, tcolorbox, enumitem

Consider

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newtcbox{\blackbox}[1][]{nobeforeafter, notitle, %sharpcorners,
     colframe=black,
     colback=black,
     top=4pt,
     left=5pt,
     right=5pt,
     bottom=2pt,
     fontupper=\sffamily\bfseries,
     colupper=white,
     tcbox raise base,
     #1}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\Large
\begin{enumerate}
\item[\blackbox1] Can the numbers be assigned automatically?
\item[\blackbox2]
\item[\blackbox3]
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

Rather than typing `\item[\blackbox1]`, `\item[\blackbox2]`, ..., `\item[\blackboxn]` for an n-item enumerate delineation, I ask how one may have the numbers within the boxes automatically assigned by Latex; analogous to the way it happens for a standard enumerate environment?

Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With `enumitem` package, with `\setlist` you can change all the lists of your document:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newtcbox{\blackbox}[1][]{nobeforeafter, notitle, %sharpcorners,
     colframe=black,
     colback=black,
     top=4pt,
     left=5pt,
     right=5pt,
     bottom=2pt,
     fontupper=\sffamily\bfseries,
     colupper=white,
     tcbox raise base,
     #1}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{label*={\blackbox{\arabic*}}}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\Large
\begin{enumerate}
\item Can the numbers be assigned automatically?
\item Another item
\item The third item
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or, in the following way, you can change only one (or some) list of your document:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newtcbox{\blackbox}[1][]{nobeforeafter, notitle, %sharpcorners,
     colframe=black,
     colback=black,
     top=4pt,
     left=5pt,
     right=5pt,
     bottom=2pt,
     fontupper=\sffamily\bfseries,
     colupper=white,
     tcbox raise base,
     #1}
     
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}\Large

... and if only the following list should be changed but not any list of your document:

\begin{enumerate}[label*={\blackbox{\arabic*}}]
\item Can the numbers be assigned automatically?
\item Another item
\item The third item
\end{enumerate}

Ordinary list:

\begin{enumerate}
\item This is an ordinary list
\item Another item
\item The third item
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You may also define your own list, with `\newlist`, and use it whenever you like. In the following, I created `blackboxlist`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newtcbox{\blackbox}[1][]{nobeforeafter, notitle, %sharpcorners,
     colframe=black,
     colback=black,
     top=4pt,
     left=5pt,
     right=5pt,
     bottom=2pt,
     fontupper=\sffamily\bfseries,
     colupper=white,
     tcbox raise base,
     #1}
     
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{blackboxlist}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[blackboxlist]{label*={\blackbox{\arabic*}}}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}\Large

Customized list:

\begin{blackboxlist}
\item Can the numbers be assigned automatically?
\item Another item
\item The third item
\end{blackboxlist}

Ordinary list:

\begin{enumerate}
\item This is an ordinary list
\item Another item
\item The third item
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As Mico pointed out, if it's important that the special numbers not protrude into the left-hand margin, you could add the option `left=0pt` to the argument of `\setlist`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newtcbox{\blackbox}[1][]{nobeforeafter, notitle, %sharpcorners,
     colframe=black,
     colback=black,
     top=4pt,
     left=5pt,
     right=5pt,
     bottom=2pt,
     fontupper=\sffamily\bfseries,
     colupper=white,
     tcbox raise base,
     #1}
     
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{blackboxlist}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[blackboxlist]{label*={\blackbox{\arabic*}},left=0pt}

\usepackage{mwe}% < -- for testing purpose only

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}\Large

\blindtext% < -- for testing purpose only


\begin{blackboxlist}
\item Can the numbers be assigned automatically?
\item Another item
\item The third item
\end{blackboxlist}

\blindtext% < -- for testing purpose only

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. If it's important that the special numbers not protrude into the left-hand margin, one could add the option `left=0pt` to the argument of `\setlist`.

Comment: @Mico Thank you for pointing that out, I added it to my answer.

Comment: Thank you most kindly for these very helpful answers.

Comment: @SamuelBowditch You're welcome! And thank you for accepting my answer.

Comment: +1. For considering all options, and going the length of adding examples for all of them. Nice one!

Comment: @orithena Thank you!